# tar.extractall() does not recognize unexpected EOF

Tags: python, tar, eof

The Python `tarfile` library does not detect a broken tar.

```
user@host$ wc -c good.tar
143360 good.tar

user@host$ head -c 130000 good.tar > cut.tar

user@host$ tar -tf cut.tar 
...
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Very nice, the command line tool  recognizes an unexpected EOF.

```
user@host$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
>>> import tarfile
>>> tar=tarfile.open('cut.tar')
>>> tar.extractall()
```

Not nice. The Python library decodes the file, but raises no exception.

How to detect unexpected EOF with the Python library? I want to avoid the `subprocess` module.

The parameter `errorlevel` does not help. I tried errorlevel=1 and errorlevel=2.

Comment: nice catch! you should consider opening a bug report and submit your solution

Comment: @knitti I opened a bug report: http://bugs.python.org/issue24259

Comment: Sadly I can't add some bounty to an existing one...

Comment: Which tar are you using?  Mine did not raise an error.

Comment: I use tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1. The bug report at python.org (see above) has a broken tar_which_is_cut.tar for testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a work around. It works with my tar files. I guess it supports not all types of objects which can be stored in a tar file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, unicode_literals, print_function
import os
import tarfile

class TarfileWhichRaisesOnEOF(tarfile.TarFile):
    def extractall(self, path=".", members=None):
        super(TarfileWhichRaisesOnEOF, self).extractall(path, members)
        if members is None:
            members = self

        for tarinfo in members:
            if not tarinfo.isfile():
                continue
            file=os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name)
            size_real=os.path.getsize(file)
            if size_real!=tarinfo.size:
                raise tarfile.ExtractError('Extracting %s: Size does not match. According to tarinfo %s and on disk %s' % (
                    tarinfo, tarinfo.size, size_real))
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Python 3 -- an `OSError` is raised regardless of the `errorlevel` setting.

Comment: Sorry, in my case setting the errorlevel does not work. This means the Python3 changes won't help here.

Comment: @guettli: you tried with 3.4?  Please add a note to http://bugs.python.org/issue24259 saying so.

Comment: I tried to extractall() the uploaded tar_which_is_cut.tar with Python 3.4.0. It raises an OSError - good. Only 2.7 affected?